# power law function in R

Tags: r, equation

Can I please confirm that I am typing the equations correctly into R?

In a journal article it says:

[image]

In the article it says: For a particle of radius 1 mm, a typical sinking velocity of 100 m d−1

They gave the two values for Cw and n

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to understand how they got 100m d-1

In R I did

```
 wsink <- ((4.23^(1-1.17))*86400) * (1^1.17) # I multiplied by 86400 because in Cw it says its in s-1 and their final value is 100 m d-1.
```

I end up with 67613.88

Am I writing the equations incorrectly in R?

Comment: Are you certain this is an R issue? Do you get the correct result if you do the calculation without R?

Comment: Haven't you just forgotten to convert mm to m? Assuming r is 1mm, it would be 0.001m and your result would be 67.6, which is much closer to 100

Comment: `(1^1.17)` is clearly wrong, `1^x` is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 mm` should be written as `1e-3 m` in the formula, such that

```
> 4.23*(1e-3)**1.17*86400
[1] 112.9416
```

Comment: what happened to the (1-n) exponent that goes with 4.23?

Comment: @LR55 The exponent is for the units of measurement, the value itself is not affected